# Algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If I have two complex curves  $f = Y^2 + X^2Y - X^3$ and $g = XY^2 + 4Y^2 + X^3$ calculating their tangent in $ P = (0,0)$ this are $Y^2$ not? Well, so how I can calculate the number of intersection in $P$?

I don't know calculate it because the tangent of f and g are equal.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this uses the fact that for every polynomial $h \in \Bbb{C}[X,Y]$ we have
$$
I(P,f \cap g)=I(P,(f+gh) \cap g)
$$

This allows you to simplify the polynomials you intersect, without changing the intersection number. For example, if $P=(0,0)$ you have
$$
I(P,(Y^2-X^3) \cap X)=I(P,Y^2 \cap X)=2
$$
where I set $h=X^2$.
So in your example above, a starting point could be
$$
\begin{align}
I(P,(Y^2+X^2Y-X^3) \cap (XY^2+4Y^2+X^3))& =I(P,(5Y^2+X^2Y+XY^2) \cap (XY^2+4Y^2+X^3)) \\
& =I(P,Y \cap (XY^2+4Y^2+X^3))\\
&+I(P,(5Y+X^2+XY) \cap (XY^2+4Y^2+X^3)) \\
& =...
\end{align}
$$
where in the last equality I have used multiplicativity of the intersection number.

I leave the rest of the computation to you, because if you don't do it yourself, you probably won't learn it. But feel free to ask further questions, if you're stuck.

Finally, some advertisement. A great book on intersection theory of plane curves (and elementary algebraic geometry in general) is Fulton's "Algebraic Curves", which is freely available on his webpage. The relevant section on intersection theory of affine plane curves is Chapter 3. Good luck!

Comment: A lot of thanks , but you can explain the next result of do $I(P,Y \cap (XY^2 + 4Y^2 + X^3)) + I(P,(5Y + X^2 + XY) \cap (XY^2 + 4Y^2 + X^3)) = $... Sorry, but I don't understand what is the process than I have to follow. Thanks

Comment: The process is the successive simplification of the polynomials involved. Look at the first equality. I've eliminated the $X^3$ from the first polynomial $Y^2+X^2Y-X^3$ by adding the second polynomial $XY^2+4Y^2+X^3$ to it. As a consequence, I can factor the $Y$ from the first polynomial in the second equality. A next possible step is in the second term of the sum to eliminate the $X^3$ from $XY^2+4Y^2+X^3$ by adding $-X(5Y+X^2+XY)$ to it. Then you should be able to factor $Y$ from the second equation, and so on. The final aim is to end up with terms like $I(P,X^m \cap Y^n)$ for some $m,n$.